# How do I define Elixir Ecto schema for a has_one / belongs_to_many association?

Tags: elixir, associations, ecto, polymorphic-associations

In the explanation of the Belongs To/Has One association at https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/ecto/associations/#belongs-tohas-one the author writes:

> Let’s say that a movie has one distributor, for example Netflix is the
>   distributor of their original film “Bright”.
>
> ...
>
> ...the Distributor schema should use the belongs_to/3 macro to allow
>   us to call distributor.movie and look up a distributor’s associated
>   movie using this foreign key.
>
> ...
>
> The has_one/3 macro functions just like the has_many/3 macro. It uses
>   the associated schema’s foreign key to look up and expose the movie’s
>   distributor. This will allow us to call movie.distributor.

Here are the schemas for their example:

```rb
defmodule Example.Distributor do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "distributors" do
    field :name, :string
    belongs_to :movie, Example.Movie
  end
end

defmodule Example.Movie do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "movies" do
    field :title, :string
    field :tagline, :string
    has_many :characters, Example.Character
    has_one :distributor, Example.Distributor # I'm new!
  end
end
```

[José Valim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588267/jos%C3%A9-valim) writes in http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/:

> The difference between has_one/3 and belongs_to/3 is that the foreign
>   key is always defined in the schema that invokes belongs_to/3.

So by using belongs_to/3 in the Distributor schema, a foreign key is defined in that schema, limiting a single distributor in this example to a single movie. (This is confirmed by the example writer's "...to allow us to call distributor.movie and look up a distributor’s associated movie using this foreign key.")

How would I define the schema if I want a movie to have one distributor, but a single distributor to have one **or more** movies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reverse it.

If a movie has only one distributor, you put the foreign key in its schema.

And then when you need to find movies for one specific distributor, you just find all the movies which have `distributor_id` foreign key referencing the distributor's id.

```rb
defmodule Example.Movie do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "movies" do
    field :title, :string
    field :tagline, :string
    has_many :characters, Example.Character
    belongs_to :distributor, Example.Distributor
  end
end
```

```rb
defmodule Example.Distributor do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "distributors" do
    field :name, :string
    has_many :movies, Example.Movie
  end
end
```

Comment: It's such a clear and (now) obvious answer that I feel like I asked a stupid question. But I couldn't get past wanting to assert in the schema that a movie has one distributor.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for explaining this to me!